# Xcode error when compile cocosBuilder - Unkown type name ldiv_t in stdlib.h

Tags: c++, xcode, cocosbuilder

Xcode 12.5.1 (Big Sur) has an error compiling cocosBuilder, but I can't find a reason.
Other computers (Xcode 12.4 / Catalina) say no errors occur.

source code is here
https://github.com/semozz/CocosBuilder_Test.git

error
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:142:34: Unknown type name 'ldiv_t'; did you mean 'dev_t'?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqApR.png)